# How to change the value of button on click?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code.Id is getting passed.But cant change value.Its showing annot change value of null.I need to change its value to"X" onclick.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tictactoe.css" />
</head>
<body>
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
       <tr>
          <td><input type="button" value=" " class="buttons" id="1" onclick="tictactoe(this.id)"></td>
          <td><input type="button" value=" " class="buttons" id="2" onclick="tictactoe(this.id)"></td>
          <td><input type="button" value=" " class="buttons" id="3" onclick="tictactoe(this.id)"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><input type="button" value=" " class="buttons" id="4" onclick="tictactoe(this.id)"></td>
          <td><input type="button" value=" " class="buttons" id="5" onclick="tictactoe(this.id)"></td>
          <td><input type="button" value=" " class="buttons" id="6" onclick="tictactoe(this.id)"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><input type="button" value=" " class="buttons" id="7" onclick="tictactoe(this.id)"></td>
          <td><input type="button" value=" " class="buttons" id="8" onclick="tictactoe(this.id)"></td>
          <td><input type="button" value=" " class="buttons" id="9" onclick="tictactoe(this.id)"></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tictactoe = function(id) {
    var box = document.getElementById("this.id");
    box.value = "X";
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: `var box = document.getElementById(passedArgument);` Why quotes...It will be treated at string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, hope will work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tictactoe = function(id) {
var box = document.getElementById(id);
box.value = "X";
}
```

Working example [here](http://jsbin.com/wabidaluyo/1/edit?html,output).

Answer (score 0):

It is generally not good practice to keep your onclick listeners on the HTML itself.

Additionally, make sure your ids start with letters.

The solution you are looking for can be made as follows :

HTML :

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
       <td><input type="button" value=" " class="buttons" id="b1"></td>
       <td><input type="button" value=" " class="buttons" id="b2"></td>
       <td><input type="button" value=" " class="buttons" id="b3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><input type="button" value=" " class="buttons" id="b4"></td>
       <td><input type="button" value=" " class="buttons" id="b5"></td>
       <td><input type="button" value=" " class="buttons" id="b6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><input type="button" value=" " class="buttons" id="b7"></td>
       <td><input type="button" value=" " class="buttons" id="b8"></td>
       <td><input type="button" value=" " class="buttons" id="b9"></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

And js :

```
    var setButtonListener = function (i) {
      document.getElementById('b' + i).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var current = i;
        e.target.setAttribute('value', current);
      });
    };
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      setButtonListener(i);
    }
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v0rw8xaj/)